# Изменение Shape Type в Particle System через код

Tags: c#, unity3d, particles

Каким образом можно изменить *Shape Type* через код?

Пытался напрямую

```
grave.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().shape.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.Circle;
```

Но свойство `shape` не доступно для редактирования.

```
grave.GetComponent<ParticleSystemShapeType>() = ParticleSystemShapeType.Circle;
```

Тоже не сработало по аналогичной причине.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доступ к модулям `ParticleSystem` происходит через `{ get; }` свойство, а не ссылку (увидите если наведете мышку на `.shape` или другой модуль). Из-за этого редактировать поля модуля через точку нельзя. Получите ссылку на модуль и работайте с ней.

```
ParticleSystem particles = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
var mainModule = particles.main;
mainModule.startColor = Color.red;
```